# tkinter. Сохранение настроек при выходе из приложения

Tags: python, gui, tkinter

Всем привет, Имеется 2 checkbox в приложении ,необходимо чтобы при выходе из приложения обрабатывались эти 2 checkbox.

1. checkbox - сохранение Ключа
2. checkbox - сохранение Текста

Соответственно, если пользователь выбирает все 2 checkbox, то программа при выходе должна как-то понять что она завершается и обработать эти данные - т.е записать их в файл.

Потом, при повторном запуске, она должна считать эти данные из фала(файлов) и соответственно отобразить их в приложении.

Собственно вопрос - как сделать обработку данных, именно при выходе из приложения. Если с файлами как работать понятно, то как обработать выход -нет. Вот часть программы

```
import tkinter, realize_Grons

def crupte_it(event):
    text_edit = input_text.get("1.0",'end') # обработка объекта, в тип str
    key_edit = key.get() # обработка ключа
    grans_1 = realize_Grons.Gronsphelt(text=text_edit, key=key_edit) # создание экземпляра класса
    # удаление из окна раннее зашифровоного текста, и вывод нового текста
    output_text.config(state="normal")
    output_text.delete("1.0", "end")
    output_text.insert(index="0.1", chars=grans_1.crupte())
    output_text.config(state="disabled")


root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Шифр Гронсфельда")

frame_1 = tkinter.Frame(root, bg="white")
frame_2 = tkinter.Frame(root, bg="white")
label_to_input_text = tkinter.Label(frame_1, text="Введите текст: ")
label_to_output_text = tkinter.Label(frame_1, text="Зашифрованный текст: ")
input_text = tkinter.Text(frame_1, width=40, height=20, bg="white")
output_text = tkinter.Text(frame_1, width=40, height=20, bg="white")
output_text.config(state="disabled")
# перенос слова в окне ввода текста
input_text.config(wrap="word")

label = tkinter.Label(frame_2, text="Введите Ключ смещения: ", width=20, bg="white")
key = tkinter.Entry(frame_2)
encrypt_it = tkinter.Button(frame_2, text="Зашифровать!")
user_choice_1 = tkinter.Checkbutton(frame_2, text="Сохранить Ключ")
user_choice_2 = tkinter.Checkbutton(frame_2, text="Сохранить Текст")

# Настройка frame_1 and frame_2

frame_1.grid(row=0, column=0)
frame_2.grid(row=0, column=1)

# Настройка объектов frame_1

label_to_input_text.pack()
input_text.pack()
label_to_output_text.pack()
output_text.pack()

# Настройка объектов frame_2

label.grid(row=0, column=0)
key.grid(row=1, column=0)
encrypt_it.grid(row=2, column=0)
user_choice_1.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="w")
user_choice_2.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="w")

# обработка событий

encrypt_it.bind("<Button-1>", crupte_it)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Есть событие завершения приложения.

Comment: Все что я видел - это кнопка, при нажатии на которой делается метод `root.quite()` Но это не то, что мне нужно. В этом случае биндится выход на кнопку, а мне нужно без кнопки, т.е когда выход приложения происходит через красный крестик вверху.

Comment: Есть событие по sys.exit(), оно возникает по  raise SystemExit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуй вот так:

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Шифр Гронсфельда")
# удалил всё ненужное для понимания..

def on_exit():
    ''' функция выполняемая при выходе из приложения
    '''
    print("let's do something")
    root.destroy()


root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_exit)

root.mainloop()
```

что и как делать в функции я надеюсь напишешь сам..

Answer (score 2):

Если просто нужно выполнить какое-то действие при закрытии окна, можно просто привязать действие к событию `<Destroy>`:

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()


def on_exit(event):
    # Здесь сохраняем настройки

root.bind('<Destroy>', on_exit)

root.mainloop()
```

Обработка `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` нужна в тех случаях, когда нужна возможность отменить закрытие (например, переспросить у пользователя, действительно ли он хочет закрыть приложение, и не дать приложению закрыться).

Пример из [**tkinterbook: Protocols**](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm#protocols), адаптированный под Python3:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def callback():
    if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you really wish to quit?"):
        root.destroy()

root = Tk()
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", callback)

root.mainloop()
```