# Как узнать, закрыто ли окно через крестик в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

у меня есть кнопка next, которая выполняет некоторые функции в том числе и закрытие окна. После закрытия окна открывается следующие. Мне нужно, что бы программа закрывалась при нажатии на крестик. Я уже пробовал это:`
close_app = False

```
def on_exit():
    global close_app

    close_app = Treu

if close_app:
    exit()
```

но это проверка закрылось ли вообще окно.
через кнопку окно закрывается так:

```
root_start.destroy()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [tkinter. Сохранение настроек при выходе из приложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/756586/tkinter-%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Comment: Также посмотрите вторую часть вот этого ответа: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1063624/1365